# Confused about Python 2D Array indices

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have just started learning Python. Recently, I'm having trouble understanding python 2D arrays! In C, array Dimensions/Subscripts are visual as, `int A[5][5]` `int A[5][5][5]`.

In Python, with 1 index `arr([3,5,7])` is 1D array. But with 3 indices, `([1,2,3],[7,5,4],[6,4,9])` it's considered as 2 array!

Can anybody help me to understand, how many indices can 2D array have in Python and how to recognize   dimensions of array?

Comment: Can you developpe : 
- Python does not have built-in arrays, but lists (and tuples)
- There is an `array` module but the constructor is `array()` not `arr()`
- The `numpy` module brings arrays but there the constructor is also `array()` not `arr()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those aren't indices, you're actually typing in elements.
`x = np.array([3,5,7])` looks like:

```
3 5 7
```

While `y = np.array([[1,2,3],[7,5,4],[6,4,9]])` looks like:

```
1 2 3
7 5 4
6 4 9
```

Indices are used to access elements/slices of arrays, and an N-dimensional array has N indices. So you can do `x[1]` to get `5`, and `y[1,0]` to get `7`.

Answer (score 1):

The part is that the values of the below array are integers:

```
[3, 5, 7]
```

It's a single list with numbers in it, so it's only has one dimension.

But the values of the list below are also lists:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [7, 5, 4], [6, 4, 9]]
```

As you can see, it's a nested array, the values aren't integers, the values of the values are integers.

Comment: @voidBrain `X=[[1, 2, 3], [7, 5, 4], [6, 4, 9]]` is a 2d array, it has 2 dimensions

Comment: I am stiil so confused! :( I cannot differentiate between 2D & 3D array! some websites are saying this 3 lists contain X=[[1, 2, 3], [7, 5, 4], [6, 4, 9]] is 2D array!!